# How to split data from time?

Tags: excel, datetime, split, excel-formula

I'm trying to split data from single cell and I need to do it with formula.

My data looks like this:

```
2016-04-12  07:45:41
```

I've tried to do this with `LEFT` function but result is just numbers and changing cell type does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract date:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))
=TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

To extract time:

```
=TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1))
=TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss")
```

There are many other ways, it depends if you need to do any other calculations on this cell.

Answer (score 2):

I am uploading a sample document which has DateTime in Column A. We want to split the date in Column B and the Time in Column C. To accomplish this separation, we must keep in mind that the value of 1 represents 1 day. Time is a fraction of a day, for example, 0.33333 is 8 hours (1 / 3 of a day).

[image]

So, to extract the date, you can now get the full value of column A using the INT function (INT returns the integer value of a cell).

> B1 = INT(A1), drag down to copy the formula in the whole column. Don't forget to format column B as "Date"

To extract the time, simply subtract the data in column A with the entire value calculated in column B.

> C1 = (A1 - B1), copy the formula, format column C as "Time"